# Creating settings scene using static cells - screenshots and simple test case attached

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have prepared a very simple test case project [MyStaticCells at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/q5/MyStaticCells) to demonstrate my problem.

I am trying to create a settings screen in an iOS app - by using static cells (here [fullscreen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijXuV.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Below you can see the Settings View Controller (here [fullscreen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki87q.png)) more closely -

The Settings scene should provide user with 3 actions:

- Sounds on/off
- Send email to support
- Restore purchases

Because I don't know how to make some space on the top of the table view controller when using static cells - I have used 4 static cells and have put the gears icon, the title *Settings* and the *Close* button in the top static cell:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

**My 2 problems:**

1. While having the *Close* button in the top static cell works - it does not look good - because the "header" scrolls too, when the user tries to scroll the screen:

[image: iPhone screenshot]

2. When the user clicks a cell - for example to toggle the sound - this works. But it only works after the user clicks another cell:

[image: iPhone screenshot]

Here is my source code -

[SettingsViewController.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/q5/MyStaticCells/MyStaticCells/SettingsViewController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

#define THEME_COLOR_GRAY_TEXT [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.6 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0]
#define THEME_COLOR_BLUE [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255 green:175.0/255 blue:207.0/255 alpha:1.0]

@interface SettingsViewController : UITableViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTitle;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelButtonSounds;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelButtonEmail;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelButtonRestore;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelButtonSoundsOnOff;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellSounds;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellSupport;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellRestore;

- (IBAction)clickedClose:(id)sender;

@end
```

[SettingsViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/q5/MyStaticCells/MyStaticCells/SettingsViewController.m)

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL soundOn;
@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

......

- (void)refreshView
{
    if (self.soundOn)
    {
        self.labelButtonSoundsOnOff.text = @"On";
        self.labelButtonSoundsOnOff.textColor = THEME_COLOR_BLUE;
    }
    else
    {
        self.labelButtonSoundsOnOff.text = @"Off";
        self.labelButtonSoundsOnOff.textColor = THEME_COLOR_GRAY_TEXT;
    }

    NSLog(@"refreshView: %d", self.soundOn);
}

- (void)clickedSound
{
    NSLog(@"clickedSound");
    self.soundOn = !self.soundOn;
    [self refreshView];
}

- (IBAction)clickedClose:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
      didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = 
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (clickedCell == self.cellSounds)
        [self clickedSound];
    else if (clickedCell == self.cellSupport)
        [self clickedSupport];
    else if (clickedCell == self.cellRestore)
        [self clickedRestore];
}

@end
```

You can see, that I have invested lot of effort into this question, please help.

In my real project I have many scenes with custom buttons overlapped by text labels - which I would like to replace by static cells.

**UPDATE:**

After great answers by rdelmar and Viral Savaj (thank you) I have renamed the method to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, disabled bouncing and disabled selection of the top row (so that it does not change color when clicked):

[image: screenshot]

Also I have given the top row smaller height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([indexPath row] == 0 ? 70 : 120);
}
```

And clear the selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (clickedCell == self.cellSounds) {
        [self clickedSound];
    } else if (clickedCell == self.cellSupport) {
        [self clickedSupport];
    } else if (clickedCell == self.cellRestore) {
        [self clickedRestore];
    }
}
```

I still have 2 minor problems:

1. How to get rid of the grey lines between cells?
2. If I'd like to have the title and the *Close* button not in the top row - so that they don't get scrolled away and are always visible - is there a way to do it "visually" in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you make space at the top of the table view is to use the contentInset property,

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);
```

Your second problem is because you mistakenly implemented `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thank you, adding `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0);` to `viewDidLoad` does move the table view down. But I wonder if there is a *visual* way to do it - because when I add the title label and *Close* button at the top, outside the table view - then they overlap the table view in Interface Builder and it makes the storyboard more difficult to edit.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber There is no "outside" the table view when you're using a UITableViewController -- the controller's view *is* the table view. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. I would use the navigation bar to add the title and close button (in which case, you wouldn't need the inset).

Answer (score 1):

For **Problem 1**, you can put your *Title Setting* and Close button in HeaderView

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

**Problem 2.1's Solution**

Just remove all kind of **bounce** Like bounce, bounce zoom, bounce vertically from your property inspector at right side of your Storyboard picture.

**Problem 2.2's Solution**

You can reload UITableView immediately after change the sound (In function where sound changes).

HTH,  Enjoy Coding !!